# C. for loop with chars

Tags: c, pointers, char

Can you explain these outputs?

1)

```
char s[]="TvNnFs",*p;
for(p=&s[5];p>=s;p--) 
    --*p;
puts(s);
```

OUTPUT: `SuMmEr`

2)

```
char s[]="TvNnFs",*p;
for(p=&s[5]; p>=s; p--) 
    ((--*p)<'a') ? (*p+=('a'-'A')) : (*p);
puts(s);
```

OUTPUT:summer

Comment: What is it that puzzles you? What did you expect and why? Or which part exactly is unclear?

Comment: The first one shifts each letter one position in the alphabet. The second also makes the entire string lowercase.

Comment: Which symbol or instruction do you not understand?

Comment: I do understand the code.  its the statement inside the for loop that i dont understand how it works

Comment: @ThomasJager  Ye o got that ,  the lowercase of the string are now uppercase and the same with uppercase (talking about the output . code (1)) .
Im just asking why it is doing that? (especially on the code 2 , cause i can understand the --*p on code 1 ) .

Comment: plus how F is swifting to u?

Comment: @ThanosKazakis what F ? please read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
char s[]="TvNnFs",*p;
```

where `s` is an array of characters and `p` is character pointer, is looks like below

```
 s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
  ------------------------------------------
 |  T  |  v  |  N  |  n  |  F  |  s  |  \0  |
  ------------------------------------------
 s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106.. (assume 0x100 is base address of s)
```

Next, the `for` loop

```
for(p=&s[5];p>=s;p--) 
    --*p;
```

Here `p=&s[5]` the pointer `p` points to address of `s[5]` i.e `0x105`. Next is `p>=s` i.e `0x105 >= 0x100` which is true, then `--*p` executes i.e first `*p` that means value at `0x105` memory location which is `s` and decrements on that will makes `s[5]` as `r`.

Now char array `s` looks like

```
 s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
  ---------------------------------------------
 |  T  |  v  |  N  |  n  |  F  |  r(new)|  \0  |
  ---------------------------------------------
 s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106..
```

**Note :** you might interested to know that by doing `--*p` how does `s` got affected ? Its because `p` is pointing or holding the address of `s` i.e whatever changes are done on `*p` will affect indirectly to `s`.

After that `p--` happens i.e `p` now points to one location previous than before i.e `0x104`. Same operation will happens until `p` reach to `s` i.e `0x100 >= 0x100`. Finally char array `s` looks like

```
      s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
      -------------------------------------------
     |  S  |  u  |  M  |  m  |  E  |  r  |  \0  |
      -------------------------------------------
     s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106..
```

Hence it prints `SuMmEr`.

**Case 2 :**

```
char s[]="TvNnFs",*p;
for(p=&s[5]; p>=s; p--) 
((--*p)<'a')?(*p+=('a'-'A')):(*p);
puts(s);
```

Here

```
       s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
      ------------------------------------------
     |  T  |  v  |  N  |  n  |  F  |  s  |  \0  |
      ------------------------------------------
     s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106..
                                      |
                                      p points here
```

For `0x105 >= 0x100` : this

```
((--*p)<'a')?(*p+=('a'-'A')):(*p);
```

is ternary operator i.e first `((--*p)<'a')` executes, if it results in true then `(*p+=('a'-'A'))` will be the output else `(*p)`. So Here it looks like `((--*p)<'a')` i.e `'r' < 'a'` which is false so just `(*p)` but `s[5]` got changed after this due to `--*p`.

```
      s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
      ------------------------------------------
     |  T  |  v  |  N  |  n  |  F  |  r  |  \0  |
      ------------------------------------------
     s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106..
                                | 
                                p points here due to p--
```

Next, For `0x104 >= 0x100` : this

```
((--*p)<'a')?(*p+=('a'-'A')):(*p);
```

`'E' < 'a'` i.e `70 < 97` which is true so this `(*p+=('a'-'A'))` gets execute i.e

```
*p = *p + ('a' - 'A')
   = 'E' + (97 - 65)
   = 'E' + 32
*p = 'e' /* now s[4] overwritten by e(previously F) */
```

Now array looks like

```
   s[0]  s[1]   s[2]  s[3]  s[4]  s[5]  s[6]
  ------------------------------------------
 |  T  |  v  |  N  |  n  |  e  |  r  |  \0  |
  ------------------------------------------
 s 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106..
                      | 
                      p points here due to p--
```

Same operation hoes on until `0x100 >= 0x100`.

Comment: I do get it how pointer works I do get everything about the theory.  I just dont get how the prev chars (s[0] s[1] e.t.c) are being changed to SuMmEr.

Comment: It's very simple. Follow each iteration clearly. In second case, roughly telling, if `s[0]` is `T` then `--*p` makes `s[0]` as `S` i.e one char before `T` and then minus `32` makes `s`. Which part you didn't get ?